# How to call a method with self from a method with &mut self

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust, so sorry if I am doing something trivially wrong.

I have a `ConsoleApp` class which holds a vector of `Worker` objects. I want each `Worker` to own a thread and handle everything related to it.

However, I have a problem at joining the thread that is hold by the Worker.

As you can see in the code below, I have a method named `run` having a mutable reference to self.

Spawning the workers (more specifically, the threads from the workers) works alright and it requires a mutable reference to the thread.

The issue is with the joining of the workers. When I call `worker.join()`, the following error is raised:

> cannot move out of `*worker` which is behind a shared reference
>
> move occurs because `*worker` has type `models::worker::Worker`, which
> does not implement the `Copy` traitrustc(E0507)

I think I do understand the problem: the `join` function from `std::thread` expects passing the `JoinHandle` by value, not by reference. Hence, I am supposed to make the join function from `Worker` to also expect passing `self` by value. However, how can I do that given that run has `mut &self`?

ConsoleApp:

```
pub struct ConsoleApp {
  accounts: Vec<Account>,
  workers: Vec<Worker>,
}

impl ConsoleApp {
  pub fn new() -> ConsoleApp {
    return ConsoleApp { 
      accounts: initialize_accounts(),
      workers: Vec::new()
    }
  }

  pub fn run(&mut self) {
    println!("Start console app.");
    self.workers.iter_mut().for_each(|worker| worker.spawn());
    self.workers.iter().for_each(|worker| worker.join());
    println!("Stop console app.")
  }
}
```

Worker:

```
use std::thread;

pub struct Worker {
  thread_join_handle: thread::JoinHandle<()>
}

impl Worker {
  pub fn spawn(&mut self) {
    self.thread_join_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
      println!("Spawn worker");
    });
  }

  pub fn join(self) {
    self.thread_join_handle.join().expect("Couldn't join the associated threads.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious way would be to make `run()` consume `self` as well. Then you could write it like this:

```
pub fn run(mut self) {
    println!("Start console app.");
    self.workers.iter_mut().for_each(|worker| worker.spawn());
    self.workers.into_iter().for_each(|worker| worker.join());
    println!("Stop console app.")
}
```

Note the use of `into_iter()` which iterates over `workers` while taking over the contents of the vector. Of course, `self.workers.into_iter()` would not compile in a method that takes `&mut self`.

If modifying `run()` to consume `self` is not possible - for example, because you'd like to allow `run()` being invoked more than once on the same `ConsoleApp` - then you can use [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) to extract the workers from `&mut self`:

```
pub fn run(&mut self) {
    println!("Start console app.");
    self.workers.iter_mut().for_each(|worker| worker.spawn());
    std::mem::take(&mut self.workers)
        .into_iter()
        .for_each(|worker| worker.join());
    println!("Stop console app.")
}
```

`std::mem::take(&mut self.workers)` is a convenient short-hand for `std::mem::replace(&mut self.workers, Vec::default())`. It will move the value out of the reference and leave a freshly default-created value as its replacement. Since this will only move the pointer and not the contents of the vector, and since an empty vector doesn't allocate, the operation will be efficient as well as correct.

This approach will have a nice side effect of leaving `self.workers` empty for subsequent invocations of `run()`. This is one of the situation where following the borrow checker results in simply - better code.

Comment: You are right, I also tried that, but my problem was that `self.workers.iter().for_each(|worker| worker.join())` would still fail. But indeed, I should use into_iter instead and consequently, that problem also disappears. Thank you! 

Comment: @AlexandruRobert Sure, but in the question you specified `run` taking `&mut self` as a constraint. I'm pretty sure `self.workers.into_iter()` doesn't compile if `run()` takes `&mut self`...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to put thread_join_handle inside an `Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>`, and only join if it is not None.

With this approach the Worker.join can take `&mut self`, and a worker stays for your disposition after finishing (e.g. if you want to examine the results, or restart it in ConsoleApp).

Approaches by @user4815162342 are good as well.